# Which sklearn mixin declares fit and transform methods?

Tags: scikit-learn

I cannot find which `sklearn` mixin class declares the `fit` and `transform` methods.

[TransformerMixin](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.html) only declares `fit_transform`, and [`BaseEstimator`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html) does not declare `fit` (as I think it should).

I suspect this is might be intentional rather than an oversight, so I would appreciate an explanation of why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base classes are just that, **Python** base classes.

As we are in Python, we don't need to declare all the different common interfaces, but there is common code that we can factor in them:

- `TransformerMixin` declares `fit_transform`, but it's a convenience function chaining fit and transform (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py). We don't need to code it in any transformer, it will always call `fit`and then `transform`.
- `BaseEstimator` doesn't declare `fit`, because except for an empty method, there is nothing to put in there. And with duck-typing, there really is no reason for adding the empty method. But the functionality to get parameters is used throughout the package, and it's common for all estimator, so it makes sense to factor it out.

We can have the same discussion on all of `sklearn.base`, and the answer will always be: we factor the common bit, the one that we don't need to rewrite elsewhere in common interfaces, and then we use them. We don't put the definition of the interfaces, because that's not how Python works.